# Restrict C++ template arguments to containers of the same value type

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I have a C++ template function:

```
template<typename Input, typename Output>
void Process(const Input &in, Output *out) {
  ...
}
```

1. How can I make it a compile error with a friendly error message if it's called with containers of different types? For example, the call `set<int> sout; Process(vector<int>(), &sout);` should work, but `vector<unsigned> vout; Process(vector<int>(), &vout);` should be a compile error.
2. How can I make it a compile error with a friendly error message if it's called with containers which are not mutually convertible? For example, the calls above should work, but `struct A {}; struct B {}; vector<B> vbout; Process(vector<A>(), &vbout);` should be a compile error. `

Comment: 1. you can use static_assert with is_same .2) static _assert with is_convertible. but there could be lot other ways.

Comment: Make your input and output parameters the same type and the compiler will do that for you.  The messages may not be the friendliest though.

Comment: @TimDave: How would the compiler do 1. for me? I was explicitly asking for friendly error messages. How do I get that? Do you have any other suggestion than Dietmar Kühl's answer?

Comment: Using template meta programming can get better error messages but the technique can be very complicated.  The solution provided will work.  As I noted, the output may not be friendly :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just `static_assert()` that the `value_type`s of the two type are the same:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename Input::value_type, typename Output::value_type>::value,
              "the containers passed to Process() need to have the same value_type");
```

If you want your types to be convertible, you'd use `std::is_convertible` instead:

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<typename Input::value_type, typename Output::value_type>::value,
              "the value_type of the source container passed to Process() needs to be convertible to the value_type of the target container");
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: The error message of the second `static_assert` does not match the check. Also, the *passed to Process()* bit could be left out. The `static_assert` will point to the right location already.

Comment: @IInspectable: er, yes - not the containers need to be convertible but the values. I updated the message! Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to remove all other warnings and errors in the function body? They just spam the stderr.

Comment: Is there a solution which works with `g++ -std=c++98`?

Comment: This is probably a good use of static assertions. The alternative would be to use `enable_if` to not even provide the overload if it doesn't make sense, but the error would be significantly less friendly, and this isn't really a situation where overload proliferation is an issue.